# How to test the text of the second element in cypress?

Tags: cypress

I can test the first element of the Dom element but I don't know how to get the second element?

```
 it('should display highlight', () => {
            const highlights = cy.get(`.${pageClass} .page_highlight`);
            highlights.should('have.length', 2);
            highlights.first().should('contain.text', translations.highlight);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for your case.

1. Since the total number of elements is just two in your case, you can use something called `last`. You can read more [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/last).
2. If the number of elements is dynamic, you can use something called `eq` and pass the order of element as an index. You can read more [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq).

Comment: thanks another question. I wanna use this test in many places but I don't want repeat the code is there anyway to reuse this one?

Comment: As per my knowledge, you can not reuse the test itself. but you can extract the code into a reusable function and use that in both the tests.